# Android AlarmManager without specific pattern

Tags: android, alarmmanager

What if i want to run my code multiple time without any pattern,like 9am,10pm then again tomorrow at same time how to do that with one AlarmManager object?

Comment: You could either set single-shot alarms for each individual date/time, or set daily repeating alarms for each given time. Do note, however, that repeating alarms are inexact since KitKat.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but can you please tell me is there any another way for exact timing?

Comment: As mentioned in the docs for [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), if you want exact repeating alarms, you'll have to use a `setExact*()` method, and set the alarm again for the desired interval when it fires. Note that this only applies if you're running under KitKat or above, _and_ your `targetSdkVersion`>=19, but this is usually the case these days.

Comment: Thank you again,i get it